# How to save LaTLang in Android

Tags: android

Hi dears I am searching location from google map and getting it.Now I want to save it so that I can use it again by getting from database. Now tell me How I save it and How I retrieve it from database in LatLang form
here is My code for  for searching location from map.

```html
LatLng latLng;
 btn_find.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                // Getting user input location
                String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

                if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                    new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
 private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

        @Override
        protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            List<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

            if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                        address.getCountryName());

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);

                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Locate the first location
                if(i==0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
    }
```

now tell me please that how I save this location by save button ?

Comment: Try creating database by yourself and if you face any problem, post it here.

Comment: You have to save the latitude and longitude separately in the database.

Comment: you just write only two lines to save latlang separately or combined i am just confused with that I will manage my database please

Comment: did you create your db?

Comment: no till now i am just looking for solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SharedPrefrence for this like the following

declare `SharedPreferences settings;`

```
 settings = context.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", 0);  //global declaration in oncreate
```

inside onPost of assync task

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List addresses) {

```
        if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Clears all the existing markers on the map
        googleMap.clear();

        // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
        for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){

            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
```

editor.putString("latitude", Double.toString(address.getLatitude().toString()));'
editor.putString("longitude", Double.toString(address.getLongitude()));
editor.commit();

```
            String addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
                    address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
                    address.getCountryName());

            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(addressText);

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Locate the first location
            if(i==0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

to get the values

```
String latitude=settings.getString("latitude","0");
String longitude=settings.getString("longitude","0");
double lati = Double.parseDouble(lat);
double lngi = Double.parseDouble(lng);
```

LatLng LOCATION = new LatLng(lati, lngi);

Answer (score 0):

```
To save in the database;

 DBLocation helper1=new DBLocation(getBaseContext());
                database = helper1.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ONLINELOCATION_lATITUDE, latitude);
                values.put(ONLINELOCATION_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                Log.i("Insert Into Database","Insert");
                database.insert(ONLINELOCATION_TABLE, null, values);
```

To retrieve:

```
Cursor callpending_cursor=null;
                    database=helper1.getReadableDatabase();
                    callpending_cursor=database.query(ONLINELOCATION_TABLE, new String[] {ONLINELOCATION_ID,ONLINELOCATION_AID_ID,ONLINELOCATION_USERID_ID,ONLINELOCATION_lATITUDE,ONLINELOCATION_LONGITUDE,ONLINELOCATION_ID +" DESC"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                    Log.i("step8","step8");
                    //callpending_cursor.moveToLast();
                    if(!callpending_cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                        callpending_cursor.moveToFirst();
                        do{
                            Log.i("step9","step9"); 
                            String callpending_id=callpending_cursor.getString(0);
                            Aid_ID=callpending_cursor.getString(1);
                            USER_Id=callpending_cursor.getString(2);
                                USER_Latitude=callpending_cursor.getString(3);
                                USER_Longitude=callpending_cursor.getString(4);



                                callpending_cursor.moveToNext();
```